Has anyone used langchain with openai recently? I am getting lots of version incompatible errors when trying install and run?
I am trying to run the below code which i saw from a tutorial. I am trying to run openai api and generate some blog titles.
from langchain.prompts.chat import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
import os

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'key'

# Initialize the OpenAI chat model
llm = ChatOpenAI(
    model="gpt-4o-2024-08-06",
    temperature=0.9,
    max_tokens=60,
    n=1,
    verbose=False,
)

# Define the prompt template for clickbait headline generation
template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
    ("system", "You are a creative and persuasive headline writer for a news website aiming to rank on the first page of Google."),
    ("human", "Generate the most eye-catching, clickbait headline possible for the given news article title: '{article_title}'."),
])

# User input for the article title
article_title = input("Enter the news article title: ")

# Chain prompt and LLM
chain = template | llm

# Generate and print the clickbait headline
clickbait_headline = chain.invoke({"article_title": article_title})
print(clickbait_headline)


and I am getting the error
ImportError: cannot import name 'PREPARE_METHODS' from 'pydantic._internal._std_types_schema' 

I am trying to run the code in windows 11 and in vs code.
The Problem:
It appears there is a compatibility issue between langchain_openai, langchain, and pydantic.
The error seems to arise due to changes in pydantic, where PREPARE_METHODS might have been deprecated or moved.
My Questions:
How can I resolve this version conflict?
Are there specific versions of langchain, langchain_openai, pydantic, and langsmith that are known to work well together?
Is there an alternative approach to make this code run?
Should I be considering a different implementation to avoid these issues altogether?
Can someone please help me find the correct versions of library o install? Its 2024 it should not be this complicated. I tried installing langchain in a virtual environment to downgrade to old versions but nothing worked. I tried running the code by installing old langchain in virtual env but still got same errors

Had the same problem

If you need an answer to your question, we would need to know which versions of the libraries you use.
